# PL/SQL: ORA-00933 command not properly ended

Tags: sql, plsql, ora-00933

hello Im trying this query:

```
DECLARE
v_week NUMBER;

BEGIN
SELECT WEEK FROM WEEKDESTINATION INTO (v_week)
WHERE STARTDATE BETWEEN '02-JAN-2010'AND '09-JAN-2010';
END;
```

but it throws  the following  error:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

please help

Answer (score 6):

Should be

```
SELECT WEEK INTO v_week FROM WEEKDESTINATION
where .......
```